# Create unique IDs to my objects

Tags: java

I have basic knowledge of java and I want to create unique ids for my employees , but I also don't want to use java.util.UUID . How can I do that ? and where and what method should I add to my code ? Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<Employees> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employees emp =new Employees(15, "xx", 23);
        Main.add(emp);        
    }

    public static void delete(int id) {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }

    public static void updateName(int id, String name) {
        get(id).name=name;
    }

    public static void updateAge(int id, int age) {
        get(id).age=age;
    }

    public static Employees get(int id) {
        for(Employees emp : list)
            if(emp.id==id)
                return emp;
        throw new RuntimeException("Employees with id : "+id+" not found");
    }

}
class Employees {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id ;

    public Employees(int id, String name, int age) {
        //super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

   @Override
    public String toString() {

        return id+" : "+" "+name+", "+age+" ans";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main.add()` are you sure ? ^^ and EmployeeS with an s ? Easy way would be to have a static counter in Employees's class and to use as ID and increment it

Comment: UUID means ***Universally Unique Identifier***... so IT IS AN ID... why dont you want to use it`?

Comment: In the _get_ function, I suggest to not use the _RuntimeException_, but instead, use [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a static variable, which will be used to have an id, and after assignment it will be incremented, to assure that the next one will be different :

```
class Employees {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id ;
    static int counter = 0;

    public Employees(String name, int age) {
        this.id = counter++;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
  }
```

So you can remove the `int id` in the constructor

---

Also :

- `Main.add(emp)` is wrong and may be replaced by `list.add(emp)`
- `updateName` and `updateAge` may use `setters` defined in `Employees` to follow conventions (and better separate classes, and set attribute visibility to private)

Comment: @M.Maria you're welcome, you may think about vote up , or better : accept the answer ;)

Comment: for the delete() method , it doesn't accept an id as argument , should I replace it with something else ?

Comment: `public static void delete(int id) {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }` is fine

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try using `Random` java class.

import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

```
public class EmpUniqueId {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int empid1 =generateDummySSNNumber();
        Employees emp1 = new Employees(empid1 , "xx", 23);

        int empid2 =generateDummySSNNumber();
        Employees emp2 = new Employees(empid2, "xx", 23);
         ArrayList<Employees> list = new ArrayList();
         list.add(emp1);
         list.add(emp2);
         for (Employees object: list) {
                System.out.println("Employees id is :-"+object.getId());
            }
    }

    public static int generateDummySSNNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int min, max;
        min = 1;
        max = 2000;
        int num = random.nextInt(min);
        int num1 = random.nextInt(max);
        System.out.println("Random Number between given range is " + num1);


        return num1;
    }
}



class Employees {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Employees(int id, String name, int age) {
        //super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

   @Override
    public String toString() {

        return id+" : "+" "+name+", "+age+" ans";
    }
}
```